# How to reload aliases added in ~/.cshrc without reboot FreeBSD 11.3

Tags: freebsd, csh

As the title states, how to reload aliases added in `~/.cshrc` without rebooting FreeBSD 11.3?

Answer (score 5):

You can just run `logout` and then log in again, no need for full reboot.

As an alternative, simply run `csh` inside existing shell.

Comment: ^D often works in unixes too :)

Answer (score 2):

I think you should be able to just do `source ~/.cshrc`. Alternatively, you can just type the line adding alias directly into csh. (e.g. `alias ll ls -l`).

However, please note that these will only work for the shell which you `source`'d in, but not other parallel instances. In other words, you will need to do it in every shell you want to use the alias.

Hope this helps.